# Delete characters between specific characters using sed

Tags: regex, linux, bash, unix, sed

I am given this paragraph:

`*Cast and characters
* Bob Denver is Gilligan, the inept, accident-prone First Mate
(affectionately known as "Little Buddy" by "the Shipper") of the SS Minnow. Denver was not the first choice to play Gilligan; actor Jerry Van Dyke, phone 210-222-3333, was offered the role on 2/11/1963, but he turned it down, believing that the show would never be successful. He chose instead to play the lead in My Mother the Car, which premiered the following year and was cancelled after one season. The producers looked to Bob Denver, the actor who had played Maynard G. Krebs, ss #111-22-3333, the goofy but lovable beatnik in The Many Loves of Dobie Gillis. None of the show's episodes ever specified Gilligan's full name or clearly indicated whether "Gilligan" was the character's first name or his last. In the DVD collection, Sherwood Schwartz states that he preferred the full name of "%Willy Gilligan%" for the character.`

My goal is to make `"%Willy Gillgan%"` into `""` using sed. I have tried `s/%[^%]*%//` but it also interferes with another sed command `s/[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{4}/%%%-%%/%%%%/` that changes `#111-22-3333` into `#%%%-%%-%%%%`. It deletes 2 %'s turning into `#%-%%-%%%%` incorrectly.

Here are my other sed commands incase it might interfere with something else:
`s+([0-9]{1,2})-([0-9]{1,2})-([0-9]{4})+\3-\2-\1+g` converts date format

`/[*]\s/i\
\n* ATTENTION *\n` adds the line * ATTENTION * and a newline when it encounters "* " anywhere in the paragraph.

This is what my script file looks like:

`s/[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{4}/%%%-%%/%%%%/`

`s+([0-9]{1,2})-([0-9]{1,2})-([0-9]{4})+\3-\2-\1+g`

`s/%[^%]*%//`

`/[*]\s/i\
\n* ATTENTION *\n`

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you change the order of the commands?

Comment: Yeah I've tried changing the order of the commands, but it still deletes it. @WiktorStribiżew

Comment: @OldLettuce If reversing the order didn't work, then you really need to show, clearly and explicitly, your exact sed command.

Comment: @John1024 All of my sed commands are in the description above. They are in a script file and are invoked from another script with the commands sed -r -f filename. I have tried putting `s/%[^%]*%` before `s/[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{4}/%%%-%%/%%%%/` but it still deletes the 2 % symbols.

Comment: @OldLettuce Don't make us guess what the script file looks like.  Put the script file in your question.  (If if is long, then, consistent with [mcve], remove any parts  that aren't necessary to demonstrate the problem.)

Comment: @John1024 Sorry about that. Completely new to here. I have added in my script file now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
$ cat script.sed
s/%[^%]*%//g
s/[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{4}/%%%-%%-%%%%/g
s+([0-9]{1,2})[/-]([0-9]{1,2})[/-]([0-9]{4})+\3-\2-\1+g
/[*]\s/i\
\n* ATTENTION *\n
```

This produces the output:

```
$ sed -Ef script.sed text
*Cast and characters

* ATTENTION *

* Bob Denver is Gilligan, the inept, accident-prone First Mate
(affectionately known as "Little Buddy" by "the Shipper") of the SS Minnow. Denver was not the first choice to play Gilligan; actor Jerry Van Dyke, phone 210-222-3333, was offered the role on 1963-11-2, but he turned it down, believing that the show would never be successful. He chose instead to play the lead in My Mother the Car, which premiered the following year and was cancelled after one season. The producers looked to Bob Denver, the actor who had played Maynard G. Krebs, ss #%%%-%%-%%%%, the goofy but lovable beatnik in The Many Loves of Dobie Gillis. None of the show's episodes ever specified Gilligan's full name or clearly indicated whether "Gilligan" was the character's first name or his last. In the DVD collection, Sherwood Schwartz states that he preferred the full name of "" for the character.
```